# How to find the particular solution for Augmented Thin Plate Splines in the context of the Dual Reciprocity Boundary Element Method

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, interpolation, radial-basis-functions

In the dual reciprocity boundary element method (DRBEM) the non-homogeneous terms are expanded in terms of radial basis functions. This expansion involves approximating the solution to the linear operator in terms of the radial basis function being used.

For example with a Laplacian/Poisson operator and augmented thin plate splines (ATPS):

The radial basis function approximation of function $g(\mathbf{x})$ looks like $$ g(\mathbf{x_i})=\Sigma_{j=1}^{N}\alpha_j]\phi(||\mathbf{x_i}-\mathbf{x_j}||)_2+\Sigma_{j=1}^{M}\beta_jp_j(\mathbf{x_j})]$$
$$ \mathbf{F}=\left[
    \begin{matrix}
    \phi(||\mathbf{x_1}-\mathbf{x_1}||)_2 & \cdots & \phi(||\mathbf{x_1}-\mathbf{x_N}||)_2 \\
    \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    \phi(||\mathbf{x_N}-\mathbf{x_1}||)_2  & \cdots & \phi(||\mathbf{x_N}-\mathbf{x_N}||)_2  \\
    \end{matrix}\right]
$$
$$ \mathbf{\alpha}=\left[\begin{matrix}
\mathbf{\alpha_1} \\
\vdots \\
\mathbf{\alpha_N} \\
\end{matrix}\right]$$

For ATPS (Augmented Thin Plate Splines) the matrix of radial basis functions becomes:
$$ \mathbf{x_i}=(x_i,y_i) $$
$$ r=\sqrt{ (x_i-x_j)^2 + (y_i+y_j)^2 }=||\mathbf{x_i}-\mathbf{x_j}|| $$
$$f(\mathbf{x_i})=\Sigma_{j=1}^{N}\alpha_j r^2 log(r) + \beta_1+\beta_2x_j+\beta_3y_j $$

$$\Sigma_{j=1}^N \alpha_j=\Sigma_{j=1}^N \alpha_j x_j=\Sigma_{j=1}^N \alpha_j y_j=0
 $$

$$ \mathbf{P}= \left[
    \begin{matrix}
    1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\
    x_1 & x_2 & \cdots & x_N \\
    y_1 & y_2 & \cdots & y_N \\
    \end{matrix} \right]
$$
$$ \mathbf{F^*}= \left[
    \begin{matrix}
    \mathbf{F} && \mathbf{P^T} \\
    \mathbf{P} && \mathbf{0} \\
    \end{matrix} \right]
$$

$$ \left[
    \begin{matrix}
    \mathbf{u} \\
    \mathbf{0} \\
    \end{matrix} \right]= \left[
    \begin{matrix}
    \mathbf{F} && \mathbf{P^T} \\
    \mathbf{P} && \mathbf{0} \\
    \end{matrix} \right]\left[
    \begin{matrix}
    \mathbf{\alpha} \\
    \mathbf{\beta} \\
    \end{matrix} \right]=\mathbf{F^*\alpha^*}
$$
In the following reference, Golberg suggests that the particular solution to this radial basis function approximation is as below:

Golberg, Michael A. "The method of fundamental solutions for Poisson's equation." Engineering Analysis with Boundary Elements 16, no. 3 (1995): 205-213.

$$ \hat{u}= \Sigma_{j=1}^{N}\alpha_j\Phi_j+\Sigma_{j=1}^{N}\beta_j\Psi_j$$

where $ \nabla^2\Phi_j=\Sigma_{j=1}^{N}\alpha_j r^2 log(r)$ and $\nabla^2\Psi_j= \beta_1+\beta_2x_j+\beta_3y_j $

Golberg finds (incorrectly) that $$\Phi=\frac{r^4 log(r)}{16} - \frac{r^3}{32}$$ When the actual result is $$\Phi=\frac{r^4 log(r)}{16} - \frac{r^4}{32}$$
The error is probably a simple typo.

Golberg goes on to say that $$\Psi= \frac{x^2+y^2}{4} + \frac{x^3}{6} + \frac{y^3}{6}$$

**How does he obtain this result?**

**Why would this be the desired particular solution instead of something that is symmetric like with the boundary element solution kernel and the thin plate spline particular solution?**

**The other references I can find for ATPS in the literature related to DRBEM either suggest that obtaining the particular solutions is trivial or that they can be found in the literature. Some suggest that the polynomial particular solutions are obtained by the method of unknown coefficients.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your particular solution isn't correct. Once you add in angular dependency, the Laplacian becomes

$$ \nabla^2 \Psi = \frac{1}{\rho}\frac{\partial}{\partial \rho}\left(\rho\frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial \rho}\right) + \frac{1}{\rho^2}\frac{\partial^2 \Psi}{\partial \theta^2} $$

So $\theta$ can't be treated as a constant

Instead, you look for a solution of the form

$$ \Psi = \beta_1 f(\rho) + \beta_2 g(x) + \beta_3 h(y) $$

where each term satisfies

\begin{align}
\nabla^2 f &= \frac{1}{\rho}\frac{d}{d \rho}\left(\rho\frac{df}{d\rho}\right) = 1 \\
\nabla^2 g &= \frac{d^2 g}{dx^2} = x \\
\nabla^2 h &= \frac{d^2 h}{dy^2} = y
\end{align}

Solving each equation individually gives $f = \dfrac{\rho^2}{4} = \dfrac{x^2+y^2}{4}$, $g = \dfrac{x^3}{6}$ and $h = \dfrac{y^3}{6}$

Note that $\Psi$ can't be radially symmetric, because $\nabla^2\Psi$ itself isn't radially symmetric.

Comment: I assumed that this is what was done in the paper... But why can the laplacian only have an x and y dependence for g and h? why is it not required to be two dimensional?

Comment: The Laplacian is technically dependent on both $x$ and $y$, but notice one term is only a function of $x$ and one is only a function of $y$. Linearity allows us to separate them. Of course both can be functions of $x$ and $y$ but you're just looking for a particular solution so it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Why can we separate them here, while I would usually have to do separation of variables or something else since $\Psi$ is two dimensional? Perhaps I do not remember what linearity really means for this context.

Comment: Linearity means $\nabla^2 \Psi = \nabla^2 (\beta_1 f + \beta_2 g + \beta_3 h) = \beta_1 \nabla^2 f + \beta_2 \nabla^2 g + \beta_3\nabla^2 h$. Then you reason that since the Laplacian of $g$ is only a function of $x$, it's sufficient that $g$ is just a function of $x$. Same for $h$

Comment: That is what i thought linearity meant. I just am bothered that the laplacians are different for the $\beta_1$ term than the others since they are no longer two dimensional for the $\beta_2$ and $\beta_3$ terms.

Comment: The radially symmetric Laplacian is also one-dimensional, if you really want to be specific. It's also a function of one variable

Comment: That is true, but it is symmetric while the other one variable laplacians are not. Also, in Cartesian coordinates the radially symmetric laplacian is not one dimensional.

Comment: In polar coordinates, $\partial^2/\partial x^2$ isn't one dimensional either. You can argue that the $\partial x$ and $\partial y$ operators are still two-dimensional in a two-dimensional space, they just happen to have one component. Regardless, I don't see why this is important.

Comment: It may not be important, I assumed symmetry was important because it is important for the BEM kernel function and this is the analog to the BEM kernel on the RBF approximation side of the DRBEM equations.